# MySQL multi-column maxium sequential runs

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, sequential

I've been banging my head against the wall for days now trying to write a query for the following problem (new to MySQL).

I have a table A which has the following data

```
id, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, max
 1,  1,  2,  3,  6,  7,  8,  9,  0
 2,  1,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  0
 3,  2,  4,  5,  7,  9, 11, 12,  0
```

I need to set the max field to the maximum sequence in the row. for example, row id 1 would have a max sequence of 4 (6,7,8,9) so the max field will display 4. The numbers are always listed from smallest to largest (left to right) in the rows.

I suspect it would be something along the lines of;

```
SET @r:=0
SET @s:=0

IF(r1 + 1 = r2, IF(@r > @s, @s:=@r, @r:= @r + 1),
IF(r2 + 1 = r3, IF(@r > @s, @s:=@r, @r:= @r + 1),
IF(r3 + 1 = r4, IF(@r > @s, @s:=@r, @r:= @r + 1),
IF(r4 + 1 = r5, IF(@r > @s, @s:=@r, @r:= @r + 1),`
```

and so forth... but it doesn't seem to work as the increment only applies per line??

```
FOR i <= count(column)
IF count > sequence 
THEN sequence = count
ELSE count ++
NEXT i
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what do you exactly mean by max sequence. Is it max contiguous run? For second row, what should it be, 6? And for 3rd row it should be 3?

Comment: so in one row you have 1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9 - from this you can see that you have two unbroken sequences (1 thru 3) and (5 thru 9), but what I'm tryin to get I suppose is the longest unbroken sequence in which case would be (5 thru 9) = 5 (including the 5). I suppose you can look at it like the maxium count of a sequence? if that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can do this in MySQL entirely, but I think this will be rather messy.

If I were you, I would do this on a client. This should work as Perl implementation:

```
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql", "user", "password");
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable");
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    my $id = $row->{id};
    my @r;
    push @r, $row->{r1}, $row->{r2}, $row->{r3},
             $row->{r4}, $row->{r5}, $row->{r6},
             $row->{r7}, $row->{r8}, $row->{r9};
    my $max = 1; # max run
    my $t = 1;   # local max run
    for (my $i = 1; $i < 9; $i++) {
        if ($r[$i] == $r[$i-1]+1) {
            $t++;
        } else {
            $t = 1;
        }
        if ($t > $max) {
            $max = $t;
        }
    }
    $dbh->do(qq{ UPDATE mytable SET max = ? WHERE id = ?}, undef,
                                   $max,         $id);
}
$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunatly I don't have any perl experience. This query will be executed only once and the result stored in the table. I could do it in excel but I have millions of rows and excel crashes (memory failure).

Comment: Well, this script can be easily converted to pretty much any other scripting language - python, ruby, etc. At the very least, logic should be very clear - it is all in for loop for r array. And, you should be able to run this Perl script as is - just supply your connection parameters

Comment: I've been surfing the net for an answer and found most sequential/run calculations are normally executed on values within a column, where as the difference here is that the values a stored in multiple columns in a row.

Comment: thanks for that, I will give it a go and let you know. Cheers

Comment: Just trying to find a way to get the script working. At the moment it crashes with "Execute failed: Mysql client ran out of memory". I suspect is becuase the table is fairly large (200MB +) and the script is loading all the results into memory. I'm trying to find a way to limit the amount of processing (i.e. 1000 row loop)

Comment: This script operates on rows one by one. It should not load everything into memory. I use similar processing everyday on really large tables (multi-gigabyte) and never had problems. Did you change this script? Also, does your table use MyISAM or InnoDB engine?

Comment: just changed the table, user and password, the mysql engine is MyISAM

Comment: MVP your a god, your script works as you have stated. Thanks for your help. I did more testing and found that if I ran the script on a test table with only 30 rows then it works perfectly no issues. If I run the script on my actual table with millions of rows then I get the error "Out of Memory (needed 2865564 bytes) DBD::mysql::execute failed MySql client ran out of memory..."

When I checked the table the 'max' field had not been updated to where the memory failed, hence my thoughts the results/table were being read into memory first and not being updated per row as the script executed??

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I still find it hard to believe that Perl script as is did not work on large table. You probably want to post this as another question - but be sure to provide exact version you are using (sans connection parameters)